# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest

Tags: java, list, eclipse, arraylist, copy

I have Object:

```
static class Truck {
    
    ArrayList<Integer> route = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    double weight = 0;
    int route_weight = 0;

    Truck() {
    }

    Truck(ArrayList<Integer> route) {
        Collections.copy(this.route, route);
    }
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

Objects pulling into this list:

```
static ArrayList<Truck> trucks=new ArrayList<Trucks>();
```

I'm trying to make a full copy of the list:

```
        ArrayList<Truck> copy=new ArrayList<>();
        copy=cloneList(trucks);
```

```
    public static ArrayList<Truck> cloneList(ArrayList<Truck> trucksList) {
        ArrayList<Truck> clonedList = new ArrayList<Truck>();
        for (Truck truck : trucks) {
            Truck w=new Truck(truck.getroute());
            clonedList.add(w);
        }
        return clonedList;
    }
```

But I'm getting a error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest
```

getroute returns:

```
[0, 9, 11, 1, 15, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.copy` requires that the size of the destination list is at least the size of the source list. Your `this.route` has a size of 0 when you try to do the copy so you get an exception.

Instead use `addAll`:

```java
Truck(ArrayList<Integer> route) {
   this.route.addAll(route);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to greg-449's answer, I would like to point out that, instead of creating your ArrayList directly when you declare it, you could also create it in the constructor instead, making use of the `ArrayList` constructor which takes another list as its argument.

That would change your code to:

```java
Truck() {
    this.route = new ArrayList<>();
}

Truck(ArrayList<Integer> route) {
    this.route = new ArrayList<>(route);
}
```

The newly created list will then contain all of the elements from the `route` list, in the same order.

Comment: This could be works :) Thanks!